# xscreensaver-settings not taking effect immediately, why?

Tags: php, linux, x11

According to the xscreensaver manual in order to get the settings changed in the .xscreensaver file to take effect immediately, we have to run the following commands:

```
xrdb < ~/.Xdefaults 
xscreensaver-command -restart
```

But even when I execute the above statements the xscreensaver runs with prior settings and the new settings only takes effect after the xscreensaver runs once after they are changed. Any solutions?

Regards,
Shreyas

PS: I am changing these settings through a php file and using exec to run the above commands after I have changed the settings.